# Exception handling for non-numeric textbox with windows form in C#

Tags: c#, exception

So I have a simple form that the user can enter in a double value.

[image]

This is what my form should look like.

However, if the user intentionally or unintentionally enters a non-numeric value it would give me an error:

```
Input String was not correct format
```

I heard about a way to do this, which is called exception handling. How do I make my own error message so that the program does not crash?

Comment: How about reading some docs?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

Comment: I assume you are using one of the many `Parse` methods to convert the string to a number. Instead  use `TryParse`. This won't crash if it can't convert it.

Comment: Egad. Although you may be learning exception handling, once you've done so please don't use it in this way. As a rule, don't use exceptions and message boxes to respond to user input when you could constrain input and present non-interruptive messages instead. For example, you could handle a TextBox event to ignore non-numeric keys, and if needed make a warning message visible if a non-numeric key is pressed. At this early stage such considerations may be premature, but please keep them in mind as you progress in your understanding of UI development. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code if you want to use exceptions:

```
try
{
    Double d = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your custom message");
}
```

Comment: My program would run smoothly without crash but the variable "ex" is never used? What's it for?

Comment: Oh so catch() method must take in a parameter therefore creating a new variable? What does that variable do though afterwards? I want to also make my program efficent.

Comment: @Mike No need to declare a variable as Szymon says. Just try `catch (FormatException)`

Comment: @L.B Thanks! Didn't know that (blush). You can learn something new every day! I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Then Why do you use words like `that's the requirement of C#`. People may  belive it.

Comment: Because I thought so before you told me otherwise. You're right. Deleted the comments to so that no one gets confused.

Answer (score 5):

Use double.TryParse()...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double dbl;
        if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out dbl))
        {
            // ... do something with "dbl" in here ...

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text, "Please enter a valid double!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok it worked but for some reason, if I pressed the enter button on a wrong answer, it would continue to take this as a zero value. The purpose of my program is to let the user input 10 values. But it will still count as a count even if the user just presses enter. How do I fix that?

Comment: That would be more related to what you do with the value AFTER it was converted to a double.  We can't see that code.  I'd ask another question specifically about that, and show your updated code.